# Combinations Two Numbers (x and y)

Tags: c

I wanted to solve a problem that is a combination of x and y (in this case 11 and 15) and check if the number (c) is a combination of those numbers with YES or NO
11x + 15y = c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int separate_as(int c, int a, int b, int *x, int *y)
{
    *x = 0;
    for (; c % b != 0 && (c > a); c -= a, (*x)++);
    if (c < a && c < b) return -1;
    
    *y = c / b;
    
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int times;
    int c;
    int x,y;

    scanf("%d", &times);
    for (int i=0; i<times; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &c);
        

    }
    for (int z=0; z<times; z++) 
        {
            
            if (separate_as(c, 15, 11, &x, &y) == -1)
            {
            printf("NO\n");
            
        }
        
            else if (separate_as(c, 15, 11, &x, &y) == 0)
            {
            printf("YES\n");
            
        }
        else
        {
        printf("NO\n");
        }
        }   
        
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Input:

```
5 (the number of n input)
89
234
876
99
12
```

### Output:

```
YES
YES
YES
YES
YES
```

### Expected output:

```
YES
YES
YES
YES
NO
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the output and expected output; that puts you ahead of 50% of Stack Overflow questions, but it's still not really clear what you are doing.  Why are you scanning into `c` multiple times?  Only the last value entered by the user will be stored in `c`  and the other ones will be lost.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I scan iterate c for the amount of int times so that I will get the amount of times input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fun little problem.
But it looks like you made it awfully complex in your code.
Here's an easy solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
    const int factor1 = 11;
    const int factor2 = 15;
    
    const int input[] = {89, 234, 876, 99, 12};
    const int n = 5;
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        bool solution = false;
        for(int x=0; x <= input[i]/factor1; ++x)
        {
            int y = (input[i]-factor1*x)/factor2;
            if (factor1*x + factor2*y == input[i])
            {
                printf("%d = %d*%d + %d*%d\n", input[i], factor1, x, factor2, y);
                solution = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("Input %d: Solution %s\n\n", input[i], solution? "YES" : "NO");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5380KB
89 = 11*4 + 15*3
Input 89: Solution YES

234 = 11*9 + 15*9
Input 234: Solution YES

876 = 11*6 + 15*54
Input 876: Solution YES

99 = 11*9 + 15*0
Input 99: Solution YES

Input 12: Solution NO
```

Comment: hmm thx but I wanted to scan the number of inputs and the number
edit : I can easily edit it thank you sir :)

Comment: I did not bother with the input-loop. It is trivial, and not a key part of the program. You can do the input yourself.

Comment: what about like 99 why is it NO? isn't like 11*9 + 15*0 = 99?

Comment: I had a bug.  It took me a moment to find and fix the bug.  Fixed now.

Comment: can you mention out the bug?, can add a new knowledge to my learning

Comment: You can review the history of my edits here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74617743/revisions and see the changes I made.